# DAX. Power BI. Profit Potential calculate

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics, powerbi-desktop

Can anybody help?
Have formula for calculate Profit Potential:

> Profit Potential = (Profit / days_in_stock) * selected_period_days

Have data with columns:
**Date, SKU(product_id), Profit, Stock**

Trying too calculate Profit Potential by using this DAX script:

```
Profit Potential = 
VAR days_in = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(lost_profit_report), FILTER(lost_profit_report, [SKU] = EARLIER([SKU]) && [Stock] > 0))
VAR period_days = DATEDIFF(MIN(lost_profit_report[Date]), MAX(lost_profit_report[Date]), DAY) + 1
RETURN
IF([Stock] = 0, 0, ([Profit] / days_in) * period_days)
```

Its working when Im choosing date period in date filter on dashboard.
But can anybody tell me, is it correct script for my formula?

Also need to count days without stock(stock = 0) for every sku

trying to:

```
Days_without_stock = 
VAR period_days = DATEDIFF(MIN(lost_profit_report[Date]), MAX(lost_profit_report[Date]), DAY) + 1

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(lost_profit_report),
    lost_profit_report[Stock] = 0,
    lost_profit_report[Date] >= period_days,
    lost_profit_report[Date] <= period_days,
    ALLEXCEPT(lost_profit_report, lost_profit_report[SKU])
)
```

But is not working when I choosing date period on date filter, its show me all dataset days_without_stock period. How can I fix it?